# How can the configuration for a monitor be saved and then applied to a different monitor?

Tags: xorg, hdmi, xrandr, vga

I have an old B&W CRT monitor connected to a Raspberry Pi via a HDMI to VGA adapter.

The CRT monitor works correctly (and not with a garbled output) only after booting the Raspberry Pi with another standard LCD monitor (connected directly via a HDMI cable) and then switching to the HDMI to VGA adapter of the CRT while running. If I boot with the CRT attached via the HDMI to VGA adapter, the output on the CRT is garbled.

I've investigated all I know how with `xrandr` configurations with no success. At this point my suspicion is that the HDMI to VGA adapter may be incorrect somehow.

So, since I can get the CRT into a working state by booting using the LCD monitor and then swapping them while the Raspberry Pi is running, I would like to save the X11 display configuration of the state of the machine after booting the machine in a permanent way, so that the configuration does not change after reboot or if it boots using a different monitor.

How can this be done?

I tried saving and restoring `~/.config/monitors.xml` but this has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Raspberry Pi may not be compatible with the HDMI to VGA converter. While the majority of HDMI to VGA converters are made for full-sized HDMI ports, the Raspberry Pi has a mini HDMI port. The garbled output you are seeing could be the consequence of problems with the signal caused by this.

A mini HDMI to VGA adapter could be used as an alternative. This ought to work with the Raspberry Pi and could offer a solution.

In terms of saving the X11 display configuration, you can use the **xrandr** command to view and modify the current display settings. You can save the current settings to a file by running **xrandr --query > /path/to/save/file**. Then, to restore the settings, you can run **xrandr --verbose --q1 /path/to/save/file.**